# Phonegap and Cortex

Tags: cordova, p2p

Cortex: https://github.com/dballard/cortex/blob/master/README
(peerjs seems not free)

Can I use these together?

I heard it is quite easy to get the source code from phone gap apps.

Is it safe to use these two things together?

How to make the p2p more safe for users?

In general, is it safe to make a p2p apps for phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use these together?

Yes, with restrictions. See below.

> I heard it is quite easy to get the source code from phone gap apps.

As simple as converting the file extension from .apk (for android apps) to .zip and extracting. All your HTML/CSS/JS files are there.

> Is it safe to use these two things together?

Safe from what aspect? Depends on what data you are attempting to share, the data validation methods you put in place, and the security you put in place.

> How to make the p2p more safe for users?

Start with treating it like a database application. Employ data validation and techniques to avoid injection/spoofing attacks.

> In general, is it safe to make a p2p apps for phone?

Depends on the security and restrictions put in place

*Question you should have asked:
Will Apple/Google allow P2P types of apps in their app stores?

I believe that iOS may not allow this type of communication to occur in an app. They typically want device to server communications for security reasons even though you can set the server to act as a passthrough for P2P-like communications. Android will not have a problem with this.

Comment: aw. I guess i should just make a mobile website, instead of an app.

Comment: and then apple publishes a framework for p2p device communication... yikes !